# MikTeX is not working, problems with Path, Mac OS

Tags: miktex, macos

I can't compile anything with my TexStudio. Miktex just stopped working. It's giving me a "path" related error, but all directories are in place.

[image]

Comment: Did you try to log off and back in? But *why* installing MiKTeX on macOS and in single user mode?

Comment: What would you propose? I actually have no idea, I am just trying to learn Latex.

Comment: Install MacTeX http://tug.org/mactex

Comment: Looks like mactex doesn't integrate with the TexStudio.

Comment: I have it, though I don't use it, and it works flawlessly.

Comment: @AleksejsNarusevics : you need to let TeXStudio know where to find the binaries. This is `/Library/TeX/texbin` for TeX Live installed by MacTeX.